# GCD program x86 assemble language

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data   
        heading     BYTE    "This is a program for GCD.........", 0
        inputX      BYTE    "Enter an integer X: ", 0
        inputY      BYTE    "Enter an integer Y: ", 0
        ansGCD      BYTE    "The value of GCD is: ", 0
        valX        DWORD   ?
        valY        DWORD   ?       

.code
main PROC       
        mov edx, OFFSET heading         ;print header
        call WriteString
        call Crlf

        mov edx, OFFSET inputX          ;input X
        call WriteString
        call ReadDec
        mov valX, eax
        call Crlf

        mov edx, OFFSET inputY          ;inputY
        call WriteString
        call ReadDec
        mov valY, eax
        call Crlf

        mov eax,DWORD ptr[valX]     ;dividend
        mov ebx,DWORD ptr[valY]     ;divisor
        push valY                       ;pushing values into stack
        push valX
        call CalcGdcI
        call Dumpregs

        exit
main ENDP


CalcGdcI PROC
        xor edx, edx
        mov eax, DWORD ptr[esp+8]       ;dividend
        mov ebx, DWORD ptr[esp+4]       ;divisor
        div ebx                         ;eax/ebx
        cmp edx, 0                      ;remainder in edx
        je L1                           ;yes: quit
        call CalcGdcI                   ;no: call CalcGdcI again
L1:
        mov eax, ebx                    ;move the divisor into eax to print
        mov edx, OFFSET ansGCD
        call WriteString
        call WriteDec                   ;Display GCD WriteInt
        call Crlf
        ret 8                           ;clean up the stack
CalcGdcI ENDP

END main
```

i'm getting wrong answer if the number is not exactly divisible, like for (54,24) but works fine with like, (10,100)...thanks

Comment: that's too bad... should we debug it for you?

Comment: no, not really...just wanted some help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should write something like (I have wrote assembly for years):

```
CalcGdcI PROC
    xor edx, edx
    mov eax, DWORD ptr[esp+8]       ;dividend
    mov ebx, DWORD ptr[esp+4]       ;divisor
loop:
    div ebx                         ;eax/ebx
    cmp edx, 0                      ;remainder in edx
    je L1                           ;yes: quit
    mov eax, ebx                    ;restart with eax = ebx
    mov ebx, edx                    ;and          ebx = edx
    jmp loop
l1: 
    ...
```

Comment: okay 1 more thing....how do we absolute a value in assembly? I mean, it will take an integer input, if the is neg then it will absolute it for further calculation

Comment: The program should compare the two input values and use the larger value for the initial dividend, and the smaller value for the initial divisor. Handling negative numbers with GCD is tricky since there needs to be an odd number of factors to end up with a negative number.  For example, what would be the GCD of 9 and -9 or the GCD of 9 and -18?